# Make a CodeMirror editor and its gutter 100% height of container

Tags: codemirror

How do I make a CodeMirror editor and its gutter 100% of the height of its parent?

For example, on jsfiddle, the editors have a 100% height gray gutter.

I've gone through the CSS trying to make everything 100% height, but no effect.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A CSS rule like `.CodeMirror { height: 100%; }` should work. Note that when the parent element changes size after the editor has been initialized, you are responsible for calling `.refresh()` on your CodeMirror instance to make sure it correctly draws itself.

Comment: At least on Safari from 9.0.1, you are relieved from such a duty to call `refresh()`!

Answer (score 18):

When showing CodeMirror write:

```
CodeMirror.setSize("100%", "100%");
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: CodeMirror.setSize is not a function  -  CodeMirror.version = "5.49.2"

Comment: You should save the CodeMirror constructor result into a variable. After that, you can call methods like '.setSize' on it.

`const cm = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(editorRef.current, {
    autofocus: true,
    lineWrapping: true,
});

cm.setSize(200, "100%");`

Comment: 100% height not workign